# Comparing generic list to an array

Tags: .net, arrays, list

Why is the generic.list slower than array?

Comment: grammar?  you question is barely comprehensible as is.

Comment: Probably need to give slack to non-english speaker.

Comment: How else will one's english get better, if no one tells them when it's especially bad?

Comment: Good point, I think editing the question to be readable would probably help the most.

Comment: Give slack? For using Y? Come on.

Comment: for the record: there was at least one downvote, but it wasnt' me.

Comment: @Joel: me neither :) It's a programming site after all. Nevertheless, my willingness to tolerate zero effort input while expecting others to give 100% in their answer is much lower than it used to be...

Comment: It would really help if you define "slower".  There are way too many operations that can be done on both a list and an array for us to interpret what you mean by "slower".

Comment: @Joel, I've learned to never assume who voted which way, since I've been accused of down-voting when I hadn't either (I did upvote your answer though).

Comment: 1. There is no entity in .NET called "generic.list".  Maybe you meant "List<T>"?

2. What operation are you trying to do?

3. What measurements have you performed to come to your conclusion?

Answer (score 5):

A generic list is slightly slower than an array, but not so you'd notice in most cases.  Mostly it has to do with the lookup being slightly more complex: List is said to use an array "under the hood", but it's not not guaranteed to keep nodes in adjacent memory in the same way in array is.

However, I saw some benchmarks way back in 2005 (can't find the link now) and difference is *very* small.

Also, the list has a number of important advantages over an array: mainly that it's trivial to add or remove items.  It's much easier to use a list when you don't know how many items you will need, or when that number will vary.  In those cases (and honestly, that's *most of the time*), you probably should *not* use an array.

Comment: good answer, since you have enough points, maybe you could edit the question.

Comment: I wasn't sure enough what the original meaning was.  Yes, I know that seems odd as I've provided an answer, but providing an potentially incorrect answer wouldn't destroy the question like an edit would.

Comment: Well, the main data block (the array) will be jut a s contiguous - but agreed: it probably isn't adjacent to the List<T> instance.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of read performance, there are two factors:

- an extra dereference (i.e. the `List<T>` will contain a `T[]` field, and has to de-reference it)
- it can't use some compiler optimisations that that exist for `T[]` - such as eliminating bounds checking during loops

However, it is much easier to add to a `List<T>`, in particular because it retains spare space - i.e. it doesn't have to resize/blit the entire array just to add a single element.