# What are the benefits to using String[] over List<String>?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, collections

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [c# array vs generic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430884/c-array-vs-generic-list)
>   [Array versus List<T>: When to use which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which)

I understand that there are several benefits of using List<>.  However, I was wondering what benefits might still exist for using arrays.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe those other two questions do not address my question.  I'm seeking reasons to use an array.  Those questions seem to advocate using a List for its widely known benefits, while I'm seeking reasons to use an array.

Answer (score 5):

You'll have a simple static structure to hold items rather than the overhead associated with a List (dynamic sizing, insertion logic, etc.).

In most cases though, those benefits are outweighed by the flexibility and adaptability of a List.

Answer (score 4):

One thing arrays have over lists is [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

```
    class Person { /* ... */}

    class Employee : Person {/* ... */}

    void DoStuff(List<Person> people) {/* ... */}

    void DoStuff(Person[] people) {/* ... */}

    void Blarg()
    {
        List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
        // ...
        DoStuff(employeeList); // this does not compile

        int employeeCount = 10;
        Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[employeeCount];
        // ...
        DoStuff(employeeArray); // this compiles
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An array is simpler than a List, so there is less overhead. If you only need the capabilities of an array, there is no reason to use a List instead.

The array is the simplest form of collection, that most other collections use in some form. A List actually uses an array internally to hold it's items.

Whenever a language construct needs a light weight throw-away collection, it uses an array. For example this code:

```
string s = "Age = " + age.ToString() + ", sex = " + sex + ", location = " + location;
```

actually becomes this code behind the scene:

```
string s = String.Concat(new string[] {
  "Age = ",
  age.ToString(),
  ", sex = ",
  sex,
  ", location = ",
  location
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would only use an array if your collection is immutable.

Edit: *Immutable* in a sense that your collection will not grow or shrink.

Comment: Arrays do not provide immutable collections. The value of any element of array can be modified using the index.

Comment: @Yogendra I think you just about missed my edit when posting.

Answer (score 0):

Speed would be the main benefit, unless you start writing your own code to insert/remove items etc.

A List uses an array internally and just manages all of the things a list does for you internally.