# Returning array value from a function inside a class (ASP.net C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, function, class

Service class

```
public string[] loadSecretQues(string email)
{
    string[] ques= new string[3];

    dbConn = new OdbcConnection(dbConnString);
    dbConn.Open();
    cmd = new OdbcCommand();
    cmd.Connection = dbConn;

    cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT q1, q2, q3 FROM Information WHERE EmailAdd = '" + email + "'", dbConn);
    dRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (dRead.Read())
    {
        if (dRead.HasRows)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
                {
                    ques[j] = dRead["q" + i].ToString();
                }
                return ques[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Page.aspx

```
protected void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmbQues.Items.Add(srvc.loadSecretQues(txtEmail.Text));
}
```

Good day guys. I am seeking for help. I want to return array values from a function inside a class. The process is, I want to retrieve 3 questions (which are string data type) from my database and store it in a combobox. Any suggestions how to retrieve those three questions? Any other ways? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Your for i loop will only process the first value 1, as you then return from your function. you need to build up surely an array of arrays and return the whole thing?

Comment: @BugFinder sorry, I don't get what you are trying to say. Can you show me how to do it, would you mind? ")

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from an inner `loop` so that rest of iterations ware cancelled, and also you miss to Dispose the command as well as close the open connection. so i suggest you to dispose the command as well as the connection before return, hence the code will be like the following:

> no need to check `dvc_mst_tdeposit`, because if it has no rows control
>   comes out from while. no need for the outer `for Loop`(i loop) since
>   (j Loop is enough to handle this scenario.

```
dRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dRead.Read())
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
         ques[j] = dRead["q" + i].ToString();
      }              
}
dRead.Close();
cmd.Dispose();
dbConn.Close();
return ques;
```

Comment: I have an error in capturing the items into combobox

- The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem)' has some invalid arguments

- cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

Comment: so you have to return List<ComboBoxItems> from the function

Answer (score 0):

Use List instead of  string array.check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430884/c-sharp-array-vs-generic-list) for advantage

```
public List<string> loadSecretQues(string email)
{
    List<string> ques=new List<string>();

    dbConn = new OdbcConnection(dbConnString);
    dbConn.Open();
    cmd = new OdbcCommand();
    cmd.Connection = dbConn;

    cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT q1, q2, q3 FROM Information WHERE EmailAdd = '" + email + "'", dbConn);
    dRead = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 if (dRead.HasRows)
  {
    while (dRead.Read())
    {
      ques.Add(dRead["yourColumnName"].ToString());
    }
  }
return ques;
}
```

Comment: Oh..! List<string> can directly converted to `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem`