# Insert int into an empty List<int> at a specific index

Tags: c#, arrays, list, collections

I realized that if my list is empty, I cannot insert something at 3rd index as it will throw an out of bounds error.

```cs
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Insert(3, 1000); //System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

I will have to pad the first and the second elements with null for me to able to insert something at the 3rd index. This seems unnecessary. But if it was an array, I can insert something to any index I want even if the previous indices are not assigned.

```cs
int[] arr = new int[100];
arr[3] = 1000; //no error
```

Is there any way that I can insert to an empty list at a specific index without padding the previous index? Or is there any other better collection?

Comment: The elements of an array of `int` are always defined - they are automatically `0`.

Comment: The equivalent of `List<int> list = new List<int>(); list.Insert(3, 1000);` is `int[] arr = new int[0]; arr[3] = 1000;`. Oddly enough it throws a different error.

Comment: To put it another way, calling `new List<int>()` defines an empty list, but calling `new int[100]` creates an array of `100` elements - so calling `new int[0]` creates an empty array.

Comment: Another perfect example of lets read the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Possibly helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430884/c-sharp-array-vs-generic-list

Comment: @MichaelRandall - That's not a duplicate. It might help the OP move forward but it doesn't answer his specific questions.

Comment: @Enigmativity which is why there was no dup hammer, though you are right *possible duplicate* could have been worded as *possibly helpful*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Other collection type

> Or is there any other better collection?

You could use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2). Usage example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

var items = new Dictionary<int, int>();
items.Add(3, 1000); // will throw error if 3 already exists

// Or update 
items[3] = 1000: // will not throw error if already exists or doesn't exist!
```

Please note that the order of the dictionary is not guaranteed. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

> The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

If you need a guarantee of the ordering, you could use a [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.8) or a
[SortedDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

var items = new SortedList<int, int>();
items.Add(3, 1000); // will throw error if 3 already exists

// Or update 
items[3] = 1000: // will not throw error if already exists or doesn't exist!
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

var items = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
items.Add(3, 1000); // will throw error if 3 already exists

// Or update 
items[3] = 1000: // will not throw error if already exists or doesn't exist!
```

The difference between SortedList and SortedDictionary is performance. Quote from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Where the two classes differ is in memory use and speed of insertion and removal

The (Sorted)Dictionary and SortedList works a bit different compared to lists and arrays. I would recommend to read the linked Microsoft documentation when using one of them.

#### `null` values in a list or array

> I will have to pad the first and the second elements with null for me to able to insert something at the 3rd index

Please note that you cannot add `null` values in a list or array of ints. That would be only possible with "nullable ints". (so `new List<int?>()`)

Comment: Correct answer. Dictionary is much more suitable for this situation.

Comment: Thanks! But in retrospective I think a SortedList is even better because of the guaranteed ordering. Updated my answer.

Comment: Or SortedDictionary ;) also added to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Inserting into a list is adding another element to the list, at the specified location. This is not the same as setting the value at an index in an array. If you have an array with 100 items in it and set the value at index 3 you still have 100 items in the array. If you have a list of 100 items in it and you insert something at index 3 you now have a list with 101 items in it.

Comment: How is this answering the specific questions that the OP asked?